# Django - models.py models.E006 passing argument to a function

Tags: python, django

My class is

```
from django.db import models
from .dir import my_func

class Upload(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
     img_content = my_func(image)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

and I'm not able to pass the image because of an E006 error
is there a way to avoid it?
because I can call the function but I need to know the name of the newly uploaded image.
thanks in advnace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a property that will obtain the value for `image`:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    @property
    def img_content(self):
        return my_func(self.image.name)
```